# Vitests: useSupabaseUser is not defined

Tags: javascript, nuxtjs3, supabase, vitest, supabase-js

I have a problem with vitest and Supabase. I use Nuxt3 in my project with `@nuxtjs/supabase` plugin. In my store I use `useSupabaseUser` from library.
I want to test component which use this store but when I started my tests I got error: `ReferenceError: useSupabaseUser is not defined`.

store file:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useUserStore = defineStore('userStore', () => {
  const user = useSupabaseUser();
  const supabaseClient = useSupabaseClient();
....
})
```

vitest file:

```
import { describe, it } from 'vitest';
import { shallowMount, VueWrapper } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { setActivePinia, createPinia } from 'pinia';

import DefaultMobileHeader from '@/components/organism/DefaultMobileHeader.vue';


describe('DefaultMobileHeader.vue', () => {
  let wrapper: VueWrapper;

  beforeAll(() => {
    setActivePinia(createPinia());
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(DefaultMobileHeader);
  });

  it('render component', () => {
    expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
...
})
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScQLV.png)

How can I fix this? Do You have any idea?

Comment: I don't see you importing `useSupabaseUser` from anywhere in your store file.

Comment: I use auto imports from nuxt